Problem Removing Seven Theme "You must add the following contributed theme and reload this page."
I have removed the Seven theme from my Drupal 10 installation as I no longer use it.

Unistalled from Appearance UI
composer remove
Deleted all references from key_value table.  SELECT * FROM key_value WHERE NAME  LIKE '%seven%'; returns no records.
Themes/Contrib folder no longer exists.
Confirmed composer.json and .lock have no references to seven

Now get the following error in the Status Report

Clearly there is a reference somewhere, but I cannot find it.  How do I remove this error?

Is there another theme in the codebase that depends on it?

In theory the only way you can see that message is if the theme is still enabled in config, or a cached version of that config. Do you use memcache/redis? What does drush pm:list --type=Theme --status="enabled" tell you? If the problem follows a deployment, did you do that deployment in two stages, first one to import the config, second one to remove the composer package? If not then the config import could have failed as trying to uninstall a missing theme


Uninstall from UI or Drush. 2. Export config. 3. Release (the updated config) and import updated config on Prod. 4. Composer remove. 5. Second release (containing just the composer.json/lock changes) and run composer install along the pipeline.


You should not do this manually in your database.

Thanks leymannx!!!   I had never used the config feature before.  I did the full export, and found 13 yml files related to the Seven theme, and another that referenced it.  I deleted the related files and removed the reference, imported the updated config, and the error is now gone!!

This answer belongs to leymannx.  I had never used the Config feature of Drupal before so had no idea "properly" removed modules might still have a reference there.  Here are the precise steps I followed to remove the error.

Admin-Configuration-Development-Configuration Synchronization-Export  Exported the full config.
Extracted the generated tar.gz into an empty folder.
Used a search tool to find all files containing "seven".
13 of them were yml files clearly related only to the Seven theme. Deleted all these files.
One other file had a reference to the Seven theme which I removed.
Made a new tar.gz of the modified set of files.
Admin-Configuration-Development-Configuration Synchronization-Import to load the new configuration to the Sync directory, then Imported all changes.

